# It is taking the user two clicks to remove a div block with javascript toggle visibility

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code and it works, somewhat, but in production it requires user to click the link twice. very weird.

Is my code out of date or something? any time you can offer would be appreciated.

js:

```
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

html:

```
                    <div id="top_min_order_alert">
                        <p>Minimum Order: $5 for carry out orders, $10 for delivery (before tax and delivery fee)</p>
                        <p>Online ordering stops 15 minutes before closing time</p>
                        <p><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('top_min_order_alert');">Ok, Got it.</a></p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Could you log the display style before you check it? It might be something other than `block`. `console.log(e.style.display);`

Comment: Notice: rather than using "onClick", consider using "event handling". And it seems unrelated to jQuery.

Comment: Use CSS classes to toggle, so much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time the user clicks the link, `e.style.display` is equal to an empty string, so the `if` takes the `else` branch and `e.style.display` is set to `block`, for this reason the `div` remains visible. Then, when the user clicks the second time, `e.style.display` is equal to `block` and it is set correctly to `none`. To fix it, check if `e.style.display` is equal to an empty string:

```
if (e.style.display === '' || e.style.display == 'block')
```

Here the complete example:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display === '' || e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div id="top_min_order_alert">
  <p>Minimum Order: $5 for carry out orders, $10 for delivery (before tax and delivery fee)</p>
  <p>Online ordering stops 15 minutes before closing time</p>
  <p><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('top_min_order_alert');">Ok, Got it.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just set `display: block` for that div in CSS.